# Code refactoring technique to encapsulate and simplify validation logic for pojo

Tags: java, design-patterns

We have a Sprint object and we have to perform some validation in our code and we have written some private helper methods like this:

```
    private boolean sprintDateEqualsIntervalStartOrEndDate(Sprint sprint, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate)
  {
    return sprint.getStartDate().isEqual(startDate) || sprint.getStartDate().isEqual(endDate) || sprint.getEndDate().isEqual(startDate) || sprint.getEndDate().isEqual(endDate);
  }

  private boolean sprintIsInBetweenTheIntervalDates(Sprint sprint, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate)
  {
    return sprint.getStartDate().isAfter(startDate) && sprint.getEndDate().isBefore(endDate);
  }

  private boolean sprintStartDateOrEndDateIsInInterval(Sprint sprint, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate)
  {
    return (sprint.getEndDate().isBefore(endDate) && sprint.getEndDate().isAfter(startDate) && sprint.getStartDate().isBefore(startDate)) ||
            (sprint.getStartDate().isBefore(endDate) && sprint.getStartDate().isAfter(startDate) && sprint.getEndDate().isAfter(endDate));
  }
```

Now as you can see there are too many validations. One approach we thought is to move some of the code inside the POJO (Sprint class) itself. Is it a good practice. I have seen code where they say pojo.someMethodOtherThenSetterGetter(...) e.t.c.

Or what do you guys recommend?

Comment: Why you say it is too many? Too many means some of them are not needed. If all are needed, it is not too many.

Comment: @mentallurg, Plain does not mean without logic. It means without dependencies. POJOs are intended to contain business logic. Here is the definition from Martin Fowler, who invented it: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html